# Up-to date agricultural land use

Tags: qgis, data, download, global

I'm looking for data on commodities (corn and potato). Tools such as USDA's cropscape (http://nassgeodata.gmu.edu/CropScape/) are great but lack global cover.

I found this dataset http://www.earthstat.org/data-download/
but this is for the year 2000 and not very recent.

Are you guys aware of any better datasets containing the location of commodity crops such as corn and potato?

Comment: This may be better suited for the Open Data SE Site which can be found at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5776/spatial-commodities-data-global